# Matrix integral operation, avoiding loops

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix (15000*3000)  The goal is to conditionally assign new  values according to the original matrix. For example, the criteria I would like to implement is this:

This is how my code is setup as of now.

```
for( i in 1:2000 ) {
    for( j in 1:15000 ) {
        if(DF[j,i]>0 && DF[j-1,i]<0) DF1[j,i]=1 
        else if (DF[j,i]<0 && DF[j-1,i]>0) DF1[j,i]=0
    }
}
```

`DF` is the original matrix.

`DF1` is the new formed matrix

Is there any other way to do this? A faster way?

I have read that loops in R should be avoided.

Comment: What are `t` and `x`? Did you intend to type `i` and `j`?

Comment: How about `DF1[DF[-1,]>0 & DF[-nrow(DF),] < 0] <- 1` etc?

Comment: I am sorry for my carelessness.if(DF[j,i]>0 &&DF[j-1,i]<0) DF1[j,i]=1
        else if (DF[j,i]<0 && DF[j-1,i]>0) DF1[j,i]=0

Comment: Thank you very much ! It  is  useful.

Comment: How about posting it as an answer? If Marat does not want to, then winnie could answer it himself...

Answer (score 0):

```
DF1[-1,][DF[-1,]>0 & DF[-nrow(DF),] < 0] <- 1
DF1[-1,][DF[-1,]<0 & DF[-nrow(DF),] > 0] <- 0
```

Because the two matrices (`DF1,[DF[-1,]>0 & DF[-nrow(DF),] < 0]`) are not the same dimension, there exists problem in
`DF1[DF[-1,]>0 & DF[-nrow(DF),] < 0] <- 1`.